# NGINX caching proxy fails with SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy

NGINX acting as a caching proxy encounters problems when fetching content from CloudFront server over HTTPS:

This is the extract from the NGINX's error log:

2014/08/14 16:08:26 [error] 27534#0: *11560993 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 82.33.49.135, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/images/media-logos/best.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://x.x.x.x:443/static/images/media-logos/best.png",

I tried different proxy setting like proxy_ssl_protocols and proxy_ssl_ciphers but no combination worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I had the exactly same problem and spent a couple of hours...
I guess you are using older version of nginx (lower than 1.7)?
In nginx 1.7 you can use [this directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name):

```
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

This will force nginx to use [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) 
Also, you should set the SSL protocols:

```
proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

For earlier versions you may be able to use this patch (but I can't verify that that is working):

http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/229

**2019 Update**: You should avoid TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 and disable them if possible. I'll leave them in the answer as they are still valid for SNI.

Comment: I'm using Cloudflare for HTTPS, which uses SNI. Making this change solved the problem - you are a godsend, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this! Since I was using multiple upstreams, I also ended up needing to add `proxy_ssl_name upstream-name.com;` for it to work.

Comment: I keep getting unknown directive "proxy_ssl_server_name" I am using nginx v1.10. Dont know why I have this problem?

Comment: @Igor-Vuk, maybe you don't have SSL compiled in nginx?

Comment: I faced same issue on nginx/1.12.2 and after adding above line it worked. Thanks

Comment: I had this same problem on 1.10.3.

Comment: `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` was the key setting, thank you