# Why is proxy_set_header Host $host; no longer working in nginx 1.8.0?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I used `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to set the host header to the original request host. In nginx 1.4.1 this was working fine. Now after upgrading to 1.8.0, I'm getting the local IP instead of the host passed by the browser.

Why did this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: I believe this is caused by a `proxy_set_header Host $host;` in `nginx.conf` and seems also to be related to the `server_name` directive. I've yet to determine exactly how they interact, but I've found setting `proxy_set_header Host $host` in your `location` directive, while also omitting the `server_name` entirely works in our case

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm having same problem... 1.7 worked, but latest in ppa (1.12) does not. Nothing I do sends correct host header upstream.

Comment: "proxy_set_header Host $http_host" should work

Answer (score 4):

Use `proxy_set_header Host $http_host`.

If `proxy_set_header Host $host;` no longer works, perhaps the meaning/ behavior of `$host` changed. `$http_host` just passes along what was sent by the browser.

Comment: Why should he do that?

Comment: If `proxy_set_header Host $host;` no longer works, perhaps because the meaning/ behvaior of $host changed, and `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` still works. `$http_host` just passes along what was sent by the browser.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the code you only blurted out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Yeah sorry, didn't have much time back then...and I thought better a quick answer, than no answer at all. ;)

Comment: Thanks - $host was not working for us on v1.6.2 as well

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. According to nginx's proxy module doc, this is needed if the host header doesn't change.

Comment: This answer should be reworded to include facts.  Right now it just sounds like a guess and a suggestion to try something else out.

Comment: `$http_host` will be problematic when using HTTP/3: https://github.com/nginx-quic/nginx-quic/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr;  I'm not sure when it changed, but newer versions of nginx -- instead of `ssl_protocols ...;` -- your conf should be:

`proxy_ssl_server_name on;
 proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25330027

===

If you were like me, you were misreading the log files and seeing `host=example.com`.  Instead of this being the host sent to the origin, this seems to mean host-as-defined-in-nginx-conf i.e. virtual host.

(Turning on `error_log debug;` showed that the host header was being correctly set.)

The log file should also contain an error like "sslv3 alert handshake failure".