# Nginx proxy_pass alert handshake failure:SSL

Tags: nginx, proxy, cloud

i have an nginx server behind a GKE ingress as a backend to serve static content (angular).

i was trying to make a route on the nginx itself to route traffic to another external service (cloud function).

when doing it with redirects like the following:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name main-app.example.com

    location /service {
      return 307 https://cloud-function-url.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

it basically works, and my angular app redirect the request of /service to the cloud function url and assuming i have cors enabled on this cloud function all works.

i wanted to do the same while proxying the request instead of redirecting it, to eliminate the cors hook.
so i've tried to update the location directive to :

```
location /service {
  proxy_pass  http://cloud-function-url.example.com;
}
```

this fails on SSL issue with the error

```
routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to upstream
```

i've tried many suggestion regarding setting specific headers without luck.
i feel i'm missing something basic.
any help will be appriciated.

10x

Comment: I am not an expert on NGINX, but I think when using NGINX as a reverse proxy for a server with SSL (which is what you are doing) have to configure SSL at NGINX end as well. You can check out the following links where users faced similar issues .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329941/nginx-caching-proxy-fails-with-ssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-handshake-fail ,   and also  https://serverfault.com/questions/583374/configure-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-with-upstream-ssl

Answer (score 0):

I’ve solved it by setting the route to a different public url which is the cloud run url instead of the cloud dns (custom domain). 10x